# How to move wordpress to subdomain, keeping only .htaccess and/OR index.php in root domain?

Tags: customization, subdomains

I would like to move all files & folders of the root directory to the subdomain & keep the root directory empty with only the .htaccess file or index.php

I tried to search a lot but fail to get the solution. Only one I got it but that is also not completely working.

https://totalwebsecuritypro.com/moving-wordpress-to-new-subdomain-or-directory/

It is working perfectly if I will move to the subdirectory, which is also mentioned on [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-i-without-url-change) but moving to the subdomain is missing.

On this site - Frontpage is working perfectly but the link to the other posts are not working well.

Comment: Subdomains and subdirectories have no inherent relationship - the task of moving the WordPress installation into a subdirectory is completely separate from [setting a subdomain as the new site and home URLs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).

Comment: ^ that is to say, do one and make sure it works, then the other. Don't try to do both at the same time as it could make troubleshooting problems much more difficult.